# A menos que vs siempre que vs siempre y cuando

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Cuál es la diferencia entre los siguientes:

> Tú puedes ir a España,  *a menos que* termines las clases de español.
>
> Tú puedes ir a España, *siempre que* termines las clases de español.
>
> Tú puedes ir a España, *siempre y cuando* termines las clases de
>   español.

¿Se usan todas las expresiones en el subjuntivo?

Answer (score 2):

La primera de las tres frases significa exactamente lo contrario de las otras dos.

> Tú puedes ir a España, a menos que termines las clases de español.

significa

> *Tú puedes ir a España **sólo si no terminas** las clases de español.*

Las otras dos frases significan lo mismo. *Siempre que* y *siempre y cuando* son equivalentes cuando se refieren a condiciones hipotéticas, y en ese caso ambas deben llevar el subjuntivo. *Siempre y cuando* es apenas un poco más enfática. Puedes darte cuenta de si funciona esta estructura cambiando *siempre que* o *siempre y cuando* por *si*.

*Siempre que* puede significar también *cuando*, *en todos los casos en que*, o bien *cada vez que*. En ese caso lleva el verbo en indicativo. Por ejemplo:

> *Él va a España siempre que puede.* = *El va a España cada vez que puede.*

Comment: Y sí, usan el subjuntivo, ¿verdad?